# Using Spring boot, I am unable to refer a class present in another jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to build a spring boot web application. I want to refer a class from another jar. The class name is SalaryHandler.
I have done the following configuration in the class having 
    @SpringBootApplication annotation:

```
@Bean
public SalaryHandler iSalary() {
    return new SalaryHandler();
}
```

In the class, where it is required, I have used autowiring annotation like this:
    package hello;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;   
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.salary.SalaryHandler;
//@Service - not working
//@Component - not working
public class SalaryDelegatorImpl implements SalaryDelegator {

    @Autowired
    private SalaryHandler iSalary;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        iSalary.testSalary();

    }

}
```

The code is compiling fine, but when this iSalary object is used to call its method, nullpointer exception is thrown.

Just to note that SalaryHandler is present inside another jar and is not using any spring annotation, its code is as below:

```
package com.salary;

public class SalaryHandler implements ISalary {

public void testSalary() {
    System.out.println("Salary test successful...");
   }

}
```

Comment: What is the setup of the class you are trying to wire into?

Comment: Like the previous commenter @Darren said if you can post the class you are trying to autowire into that will help. It's most likely that you are trying to use `@Autowire` in a non-managed class. `@Autowire` needs to be used in a Spring managed class, defined, for example, as a `@Component` or `@Service`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to attempt Autowire  with @Component. In order to get this to work, you'll have to annotate a method in your @Configuration class. Something like this should allow you to autowire the class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.package.where.my.class.is")
public class ConfigClass{

  @Bean
  public JPADataService jpaDataService(){
    return new JPADataService();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using @SpringBootApplication annotation.. i have tried giving it through scanBasePackages attribute, but that is also not working

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this. The problem was somewhere inside code, I was calling SalaryDelegatorImpl  using new operator(from inside a factory class), so that was not being managed by Spring. As a result, the @Autowired on SalaryHandler, was not working.
I changed my factory to be spring managed, and then it worked fine.

Thanks everyone for the support.